# Is it correct to say "will know French and he'll do reconciliation"?

Tags: grammaticality, grammaticality-in-context, british-english

> I can guarantee you the quality of the translation because the editor of the book **will know French and he'll do reconciliation.**

Is this part of my phrase correct? "will know French and he'll do reconciliation"

I'm trying to say the editor of the book (whoever that may be) is someone who knows French. Reconciliation is a metaphor in translation, in which the editor reconciles the translated version with the original one. In this case, we're considering an editor who knows French and he will compare a Russian Translation from a second translation with the original one which is in French.

Comment: _Know French_ is OK, but if you're recommending someone as a translator you might say 'the editor is fluent in French'. I have no idea what you mean by _do reconciliation_. Who or what is he going to reconcile, and what has that to do with translating a book?

Comment: @KateBunting I'm trying to say the editor of the book (whoever that may be) is someone who knows French. and reconciliation is a metaphor in translation, in which the editor reconciles the translated version with the original one. In this case, we're considering an editor who knows French and he will compare a Russian Translation from a second translation with the original one which is in French

Comment: "...We will choose an editor who is fluent in French and will be able to reconcile different versions"?

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you.